# Typing 4.1-0.1 returns 3.9999999999999996

Tags: javascript

When I type 4.1-0.1 into the javascript console in my browser (Chrome), or anywhere else in my code, it always returns the number 3.9999999999999996. I have also tried this in Firefox, and got the same result. I don't know if this is only my computer, or if this applies to all javascript, or if it's something simple I am overlooking. Also, sorry if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find any other situations like this, but I might not have been looking for the right thing.

Comment: Floating point math- Several different representations of real numbers have been proposed, but by far the most widely used is the floating-point representation.1 Floating-point representations have a base  (which is always assumed to be even) and a precision p. If  = 10 and p = 3, then the number 0.1 is represented as 1.00 × 10-1. If  = 2 and p = 24, then the decimal number 0.1 cannot be represented exactly, but is approximately 1.10011001100110011001101 × 2-4.


https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I wonder if there is a regular expression that can match questions like this so we can just link to that article :)

Comment: @JasonSperske try Meta this will be good idea :)